# using INSERT IGNORE across two columns

Tags: mysql

Im looking to use INSERT IGNORE so that I avoid entering duplicate fields into my database but i want to check this across **2** columns not 1.

So only if columns DateandTime **AND** Horse don't exists **together** in the same row

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shoud work with indices.

If you want to check that the values for `DateandTime` and `Horse` are both not set, give each a unique index.

If you want to check it the combinaiton of both doesn't exist jet, give them a combined index that is set to unique.

I recommend to use phpmyadmin. You can set indices in the `Structure` tab of a table.

---

There is no php needed to achive this.

---

Tt you Comment about a combined index:

```
ALTER TABLE Race_Records ADD  UNIQUE INDEX unique_index ( `Horse`, `DateandTime` ) ;
```

the `unique_index` is the name of the index. You can choose that yourself, it you warn.

All Arguments in the `()` are used as the cols, that are added to that index.

And you need to set the `UNIQUE` to make it an unique index. Otherwise it will only be a normal index that only helps with searching.

Comment: Thanks i have adjusted my tags to reflect this. I have done `ALTER TABLE  `Race_Records` ADD INDEX (  `Horse` ) ;` and also set them both to Unique but would that now be a combined index that is set to unique.

Comment: @emmaperkins I edited my answer to include an example how to do a index witl multiple cols. pls check that out.